How to establish an object styles to put luminosity to an image and fill its frame? (for a pseudo-grayscale effect in InDesign)
I learned that you can apply luminosity (from the opacity menu) to an image and then fill the frame with black to create an illusion of grayscale images in InDesign without having to work them up in PS. This is a nice workaround and pretty simple, but I'm struggling to find how to establish this as an Object Style. I thought maybe it needed to be two separate styles, but I I don't have much experience at all with Object Styles and have been struggling for a couple of days to figure this one out. Can I even apply luminosity as an Object Style?
Thanks!

There it is, I see it. Thanks a lot!

Standard method with two Object Styles
The standard way would be to have two Object Styles for this. One that adds a black background to the container frame of the image, and one that sets the Blending mode of the content frame to Luminosity.

Select the container frame of an image.
In the Swatches panel, select an RGB black as fill (not CMYK black - that will make the image brown).
In the Object Styles panel, click the Create new style button and name the Object Style something like "Outer Frame".
Select the content frame of the image.
In the Effects panel, set the Blending mode to Luminosity.
In the Object Styles panel, click the Create new style button and name the Object Style something like "Inner Frame".

Here's a gif showing the method. (I would've added it inline, but there seems to be a problem with uploading a gif at the moment.)
Hacky method with only one Object Style
Looking more into it, I actually found a way to apply this effect with only one Object Style.

Select the content frame of an image.

In the Effects panel, set the Blending mode to Luminosity.

To add a black background color, enter the Effects settings and add a Drop Shadow with the following settings:

(Notice in particular that Object Knocks Out Shadow is ticked off and remember also here to use an RGB black - not a CMYK black.)

In the Object Styles panel, click the Create new style button and name the Object Style.


This Object Style can now be applied to the content frame of an image.
Beware
I don't recommend using any of these methods for anything that really matters. You have to promise only to use this method for screen. On print it's likely to give the image an unwanted color tint for reasons I won't go into here. Besides that, the grayscale version of the image becomes rather dull and it could benefit from a custom treatment in Photoshop (where you could use actions to speed up the process).
